# Как перевести содержимое/текст страниц в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, есть ли какой-то плагин в WordPress, который переводил бы содержимое страниц на другой язык ?? То-есть задача не сделать мультиязычность, а именно перевод текста в админке, чтобы это всё не переводить в ручную через Google переводчик.

Comment: Аддоны к браузеру.